# How to make a regex syntax in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regex syntax for allowing me ASCII letters, digits, hyphens and underscores and forward slashes.

Currently I am using following syntax but it is not working

```
if (!id.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_-/]+")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ID: \"" + id
            + "\". An ID may not be the empty string and must contain only ASCII letters, digits, hyphens and underscores and forward slash.");
}
```

However when I remove the '/' from the regex it is working fine. How can I add forward slash in this condition?

I looked into regex tutorial and it has some examples but those are individual. I want to use forward slash along with ASCII letters, digits.

Comment: Escape `-`. `"[a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+")` or move to the end in the character class `"[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+")`

Comment: read point 2 of section 2.1 from **[`documenation`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1757/character-classes/9991/character-class-and-common-problems-faced-by-beginner#t=20160801073324764453)**

Comment: The document, it is very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a range with `_-/`.

Either put the hyphen at the end (and always keep it there):

```
if (!id.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+"))
                            ^
```

Or, escape the hyphen to always treat it as a literal symbol:

```
if (!id.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-/]+"))
                            ^^^
```

**NOTE**: There has been some discussion, and it has been pointed out that in case the regular expression is going to be further improved/enhanced/expanded, the best way is to escape the hyphens that should be treated as literal `-` symbols inside character classes.